# Ubuntu 16.04 not shutting down

Tags: shutdown, gui, 16.04

I have recently upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and I have had a few issues in upgrading. But I have fixed these and now everything works without any issues in the new version, with one exception

When I'm shutting down, the system doesn't completely shutdown. I have to forcefully shut it down by pressing the poweroff button.

I can use `sudo shutdown` and `sudo reboot`; these work fine, but when I shut down the system using the GUI it's not shutting down completely.

Comment: I'm using the default one. Unity

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Had the same problem**

*Steps to try resolve issue!*

what worked for me was to do a disk recheck and repair, solved the issue.

1- When you see the GRUB prompt, press Esc to get to the GRUB menu.  Choose recovery mode.  You'll see another menu that includes an fsck option.

2- run the following command from a terminal from a Live CD if you cant access GRUB menu typing the following command `fsck /dev/sda1`

3- type `reboot` after the process finishes if needed.

Should hopefully correct any inconsistencies and fix boot up hangs.

Comment: This worked for me running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Legion Y520. Thanks!