# Ubuntu restarts instead of shutting down

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

When I try to shut down my laptop, instead of shutting down it restarts. It is happening after I have updated my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04. I am using Ubuntu in dual boot with windows 8.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04 not shutting down](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762633/ubuntu-16-04-not-shutting-down)

Comment: I doubt it's a duplicate. I remember encountering this issue a while back, and it was because of some Nvidia drivers issue on systems with Nvidia Optimus. OP, is that the case for you? But anyway, I never found a solution for it unfortunately...

Comment: @AlinAndrei OP has written in question that It is happening after he has updated his ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 .

Comment: @kashish I don't see why that affects my comment. Yes, there's something going on with Ubuntu 16.04 and Nvidia drivers on Optimus laptops. I now use 16.10 and I was never able to figure out why it was occurring... anyway, just trying to help.

Comment: What happens when you shut down your system with `sudo shutdown`?

Comment: @Alin Andrei No I don't have Nvidia ,It is Intel .

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have tried all the methods of shut down ...but the problem is same always.

Comment: Also I tried formatting and reinstalling ubuntu but the problem is same again...So ,I think the problem is not in the ubuntu but something else.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so much ....I am happy that finally I got the solution...
Only we have to do is to remove grub file from  /etc/default (in any linux distros).It can be directly done by this method =>go to **computer**=>go to **etc** folder=>enter in **default**=>**remove the grub file** from there=>goto terminal and write "**sudo update-grub**"